# Mapped network drive not connecting

Tags: connection, wireless-networking, remote-connection, 3g

I have a mapped network drive which maps to a shared folder on a VPS. Whenever I connect to the mapped drive from most locations I don't have any problems. However, when I try to connect at work I get the following error message:

```
An error occured while reconnecting Z: to [path]
Microsoft Windows Network: The network path was not found.

This connection has not been restored.
```

The only difference connecting from my work environment is that I'm using a 3G MiFi Wireless Modem to connect to the Internet. So I'm wondering if this has something to do with why it's suddenly not working.

Does anyone have any ideas? All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Many 3g sticks use a highly restricted internet service that only provides the most basic ports (80, 443, 25 etc.) and block everything else.

If your mapped drive is working elsewhere, I can only recommend checking what zone your 3g internet connection is in (Public/Private etc.) and/or firewall settings. If that is all correctly set, I can only assume that your 3g service is restricted.

Also, a bit of friendly advice - try looking at setting up VPN or a similar service to your server. Having SMB (Windows File Sharing Protocol) accessible over the internet is a very bad idea on the security front.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. When I connected, I had the option of choosing the "Network Location" out of "Home", "Work" or "Public". I chose "Work" so I think this is a Private network type. I'm not sure how to check if the firewall settings are "correctly set". Thanks for the advice about setting up a VPN - I've never done that before so is it fairly easy to do something like that?

Comment: VPN ease really depends on the environment... I wrote a guide for Windows - http://blog.williamhilsum.com/2010/09/how-to-configure-windows-vpn-in-less.html I doubt it is firewall though if the same machine can access it in different places.